# Trouble calling recursive promise when promise isn't returned the second-to-last time

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, request-promise

I'm trying to recursively fetch data from an API, which returns data in pages.

I want to keep fetching data and appending the result to an array, until `hasNextPage` is false.

Here's the code I've got related to this so far:

```
function getPhaseData(cursor) {
  let cursorAddition = "";
  if (cursor === undefined) {
    cursorAddition = "";
  } else {
    cursorAddition = ' after: "' + cursor + '"';
  }
  // build the API request - have no cursor/starting position on the initial calls, but add it on the subsequent calls

  let phaseData = [];
  // eventually want to return this variable with all the data from the API

  rp({
    url: "https://app.pipefy.com/queries",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.PIPEFY_BEARER,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    mode: "no-cors",
    body:
      '{"query":"{ phase(id: 2087517) {id name cards_count cards (first: 30' +
      cursorAddition +
      ') {  pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } edges { node { id title due_date } } } }}"}'
  }).then(function(response) {
    let responseData = JSON.parse(response);

    for (var i in responseData.data.phase.cards.edges) {
      phaseData.push(responseData.data.phase.cards.edges[i]); // add the data from the first call to the phaseData array
    }

    if (responseData.data.phase.cards.pageInfo.hasNextPage) { // if next page exists
      // call function again to get the next page, starting from the cursor position
      return getPhaseData(responseData.data.phase.cards.pageInfo.endCursor).then(function(nextResponse) {
        let nextResponseData = JSON.parse(nextResponse);
        for (var i in nextResponseData.data.phase.cards.edges) {
        phaseData.push(nextResponseData.data.phase.cards.edges[i]); // add the data from the subsequent calls to the phaseData variable
      }
      });
    } else {
      return phaseData; // if no subsequent page exists, just return the phase data
    }
  });
}

getPhaseData();
```

The problem I'm having is that:

On the last iteration when `hasNextPage` is `false`, the function returns an array, instead of a promise.

This is great, but on the second-to-last iteration, we detect that `hasNextPage` is `true`, and call the function again. However, we can't do `.then()` on that result, as an array is returned instead of a promise!

The function is stopping one page short of where it should be.

The error is:
`Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

I'd appreciate any guidance, particularly around the design patterns.

I can see where this is going wrong, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Your `getPhaseData` function itself doesn't `return` anything currently.

Comment: ................ so the `return`s I have currently are just returning from the `rp` call, @Bergi? I wasn't sure whether this 'counted' as the `getPhaseData` returning something

Comment: Is there any way to re-call `rp` directly? I can't get my head around handling the disconnect between the `getPhaseData` function and the `rp` function.

Comment: Yes, they only return from the `function(response) {…}` callback function that is passed to `rp(…).then`. You will want to `return` the promise created by that `.then()` chain from the `getPhaseData` function.

Comment: Similarly, you'll want to add a `return` statement to the `then` callback after the recursive call

Comment: hmm, I want to continue after the `return getPhaseData(responseData.data.phase.cards.pageInfo.endCursor).then()`, not exit. What would I be returning there?
(also, I assume returning the promise means `return rp()...`?)

Comment: What do you mean by "continue", there's nothing else down that branch of execution? You will will want to `return phaseData` to fulfill the promise with it (as always). PS: Yes, I meant `return rp(…).then(…);`.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been thinking that `return` on all branches inside `rp` would stop the recursion - but now I see where I went wrong with that.

Comment: @Bergi if you'd like to write your comments up as an answer, I'm happy to accept the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, what you effectively have is :

```
function getPhaseData(cursor) {
    // synchronous stuff
    rp({ ... })
    .then(function(response) {
        let phaseData = someTransformOf(response);
        if (testForNextPage) {
            return getPhaseData(response.someProperty)
            .then(function(nextResponse) {
                phaseData = phaseData.concat(someTransformOf(nextResponse));
            });
        } else {
            return phaseData;
        }
    });
}
```

Several issues:

1. `getPhaseData()` returns undefined as there's no `return` in front of `rp(...).then(...);`
2. the inner .then returns undefined, therefore each level of the recursion (attempts to) deliver `undefined` to the previous level.
3. The transform of the response needs to be perfomed once, in the outer then. The inner then should receive transformed data from the next lower level of the recursion, not a raw response that needs transforming.

You are actually 90% there - the fixes are pretty simple:

```
function getPhaseData(cursor) {
    // synchronous stuff
    return rp({ ... })
 // ^^^^^^ 
    .then(function(response) {
        let phaseData = someTransformOf(response);
        if (testForNextPage) {
            return getPhaseData(response.someProperty)
            .then(function(nextResponse) {
                return phaseData.concat(nextResponse); // no need to perform the transform here, it was performed by the recursive getPhaseData() call
             // ^^^^^^
            });
        } else {
            return phaseData;
        }
    });
}
```

So now,

- `getPhaseData()` returns Promise, regardless of whether it was called internally or externally.
- each level of the recursion delivers a concatenation of data from all lower levels.
- the top level of the recursion delivers, to the original caller, a the full concatenation of all data from all lower levels (ie all pages).